# Guidelines for optimizing WebGL performance by minimizing shader/state changes

Tags: performance, opengl-es, 3d, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to get an idea of the practicality of WebGL for rendering large interior scenes, consisting of 100K's of triangles.  These triangles are distributed over many objects, and there are many materials in the scene.  On the other hand, there are no moving parts.  And the materials tend to be fairly simple, mostly based on texture maps.  There is a lot of texture map sharing .. for example all the chairs in scene will share a common map.  There is also some multitexturing - up to three textures overlaid in a material.

I've been doing a little experimentation and reading, and gather that frequently switching materials during a rendering pass will slow things down.  For example, a scene with 200K triangles will have significant performance differences, depending on whether there are 10 or 1000 objects, assuming that each time an object is displayed a new material is set up.

So it seems that if performance is important the scene should be sorted by materials so as to minimize material switching.  What I'm looking for is guidelines on how to think of the overhead of various state changes, and where do I get the biggest bang for the buck.  For example,

- what are the relative performance costs of, say, `gl.useProgram()`, `gl.uniformMatrix4fv()`, `gl.drawElements()`
- should I try to write ubershaders to minimize shader switching?
- should I try to aggregate geometry to minimize the number of `gl.drawElements()` calls

I realize that mileage may vary depending on browser, OS, and graphics hardware.  And I'm also not looking for heroic measures.  Just some guidelines from people who have already had some experience in making scenes fast.  I'll add that while I've had some experience with fixed-pipeline OpenGL programming in the past, I'm rather new to the  WebGL/OpenGL ES 2.0 way of doing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [batch, batch, batch](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8230/BatchBatchBatch.pdf)? Admittedly, it focuses on directX, but the reasoning applies to a lesser extent to Open/WebGL also: Each API call has significant overhead on the CPU. The advice is use all the API's options to share textures, use instancing (if available), write complex shaders to avoid many draw calls. So if you can draw the whole house as a single mesh in a single call, that would be better than 1000 calls for each room. Writing ubershaders is reccomended but mostly because it may allow you to remove draw calls, not because GPU state switching is expensive.

This assumes recent hardware. For low end platforms (iPad?) or Intel GMA chips, the bottlenecks will be elsewhere (like in software vertex processing).

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat helpful.  At least I learned a new term of art: "batch".  And googling 'nvidia "batch, batch, batch"' brings up useful stuff.  The games community has obviously been agonizing over this stuff for a long time.